# Why can´t I access the properties of a single entity after using retrieve <entity>?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

```
TableOperation retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>("PartitionKeyvalue", "Rowkey");
TableResult result = table.Execute(retreive);
```

Now this single entity has properties, then why cant I access them like `result.Result.(Property)`?

Do I necessarily need to loop through the single entity stored in `TableResult`?

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please try to format your questions to make them more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#retrieve-a-single-entity

Please use generic method Retrieve() to specify the type of your entity:

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Create a retrieve operation that takes a customer entity.
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>("Smith", "Ben");

// Execute the retrieve operation.
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

// Print the phone number of the result.
if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((CustomerEntity)retrievedResult.Result).PhoneNumber);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The phone number could not be retrieved.");
}
```